# how to configure FlatFileItemWriter to output the file to a ByteArrayRecource?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a situation in which the deployment server doesn't allow the application to output files to its file system ... so what i'm trying to do is to configure the `FlatFileItemWriter`  to output the result file to a static `Resource` property (multi Threading is not an issue here ) .
the current code i have is

```
...
flatFileItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource("outputBatch/users.csv"));
...
```

is there any way i can output this file to a static Resource property to be accessed later, for example `ByteArrayResource` or `InMemoryResource` .
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FlatFileItemWriter` is designed to write items to a flat file or a writable `Resource` that represents a file. Here is an excerpt from its [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemWriter.html):

```
The location of the output file is defined by a Resource and must represent a writable file.
```

So in your case, you need to use a custom writer that writes items to an in-memory resource.

Comment: I always wait for your answers, thank you Mahmoud , i can give up on the `FlatFileItemWriter` now for a custom one .

Comment: Thank you, always happy to help! If the answer helped, please accept it or upvote it.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine it would be good if you had a FlatFileItemWriter to write to ByteArrayResource for JUNIT testing. Our Jenkins build servers does not allow app to write to server.

Comment: @LlewelynJones Yes, and unfortunately there is no one provided by Spring Batch OOTB. You can create a custom one for tests if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem - I would like to write/read GCP Cloud Storages files. I use example from https://github.com/ncelq/spring-batch-gcs/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloud/sample/GSFileWriter.java but header/footer is not writed.

```
  @Bean
  @StepScope
  public GCSFileWriter<MyClass> myClassGcsWriter() throws IOException {
    final Resource outputResource = this.gcpLoader.getResource("gs://my-bucket/myfile");
    final GCSFileWriter<MyClass> writer = new GCSFileWriter<>();
    final Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()).build().getService();
    writer.setStorage(storage);
    writer.setResource(outputResource);

    final FormatterLineAggregator<MyClass> formatterLineAggregator = new FormatterLineAggregator<>();
    final BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<MyClass> beanWrapperFieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
    beanWrapperFieldExtractor.setNames(FlatFileFormatConverter.getNames(MyClass.class, false, true));
    formatterLineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(beanWrapperFieldExtractor);
    formatterLineAggregator.setFormat(FlatFileFormatConverter.getFormat(MyClass.class, true));

    writer.setShouldDeleteIfExists(true);
    writer.setLineAggregator(formatterLineAggregator);
    writer.setHeaderCallback(getFileHeaderCallback(null));
    writer.setFooterCallback(getFileFooterCallback(null));

    return writer;
  }
```

If I use standard FlatFileItemWriter header and footer are saved

```
    final Resource outputResource = new FileSystemResource("somedirectory/myfile");

// @formatter:off
return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<MyClass>()
    .name("myClassWriter")
    .resource(outputResource)
    .formatted()
    .format(FlatFileFormatConverter.getFormat(MyClass.class, true))
    .names(FlatFileFormatConverter.getNames(MyClass.class, false, true))
    .shouldDeleteIfExists(true)
    .headerCallback(getFileHeaderCallback(null))
    .footerCallback(getFileFooterCallback(null))
    .build();
// @formatter:on
```

I will be grateful for help.